# Dynamics CRM Online - Lead-to-Contact connection gets automatically created when existing contact is populated

Tags: dynamics-crm-online

On the lead, when I populate the existing contact field (field name is 'parentcontactid'); then click save; a connection between the lead and contact is automatically created. I did not qualify the lead.

How can I disable this automatic connection? When I look at the audit history of the created connection, I see that it was created by 'SYSTEM'. I could not find any existing workflows.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any documentation on this anywhere but I have the same behavior and am starting to think it is by design. A connection record (with the stakeholder role) is being created by SYSTEM when 'parentcontactid' is populated. That field also gets automatically populated when you qualify a lead and a contact is created. The system wants that stakeholder role to carry over to the opportunity so that the contact shows up in the "Stakeholders" connections grid they have on the form by default. I am going to create a regular bulk delete job to delete connections created by system that are related to a closed lead.

Answer (score -1):

What you are doing is creating the connection between the Lead and the Contact, or you are setting it at least. A lookup is the "1"-part of a 1:N relationship.

Comment: Is there a way to stop/disable the automatic creation of the connection record that is created when the lookup is populated?

Comment: No, you are connecting the two objects by using a lookup. If you just want it to read that the parent account (or whatever) is Mercedes you need to use a text field. Although I doubt that you really want to do that since it's one of the reasons why you use a CRM system, that the records are connected if they are connected in reality.

Comment: Would you agree that the connection created between the lead and the contact is a special case, built into CRM? I don't think every lookup relationship in CRM is accompanied by a connection. For example, account and primary contact OR account and parent account.

Comment: What is this Connection you are referring to? The relationship between Contact and lead works the same way as between Contact and parent account AFAIK.